# Need a custom stylelint rule or plugin that keeps kebab case, but allows --wp-- variable names

Tags: stylelint

My current styelint config enforce the kebab-case rule for variable names which is good, except... in cases where the variable name starts with --wp--. So the following would be valid:

```css
.my-class {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: var(--wp--primary-color);
}
```

But this would be invalid:

```css
.my-class {
  background-color: var(--primaryColor);
  color: var(--testing--primary-color);
}
```

I've tried the following, creating a custom plugin:

```js
const stylelint = require('stylelint');

const ruleName = 'plugin/kebab-case-or-wp-vars';
const messages = stylelint.utils.ruleMessages(ruleName, {
    expected: 'Expected custom property name to be kebab-case or start with --wp--',
});

const ruleFunction = (primaryOption, secondaryOptionObject, context) => {
    return function (root, result) {
        root.walkDecls((decl) => {
            // Check if the declaration property is a custom property
            if (!/^--/.test(decl.prop)) {
                return;
            }

            // Check if the custom property matches the pattern
            if (!/^--(wp--)?[a-z][a-z0-9-]*$/.test(decl.prop)) {
                stylelint.utils.report({
                    message: messages.expected,
                    node: decl,
                    result,
                    ruleName,
                });
            }
        });
    };
};

ruleFunction.ruleName = ruleName;
ruleFunction.messages = messages;

module.exports = stylelint.createPlugin(ruleName, ruleFunction);
```

With this config:

```js
module.exports = {
    extends: ['@wordpress/stylelint-config'],
    plugins: [
        'stylelint-declaration-strict-value',
        'stylelint-order',
        './stylelint-kebab-case-or-wp-vars',
    ],
    rules: {
        'scale-unlimited/declaration-strict-value': [
            '/color/',
            { ignoreValues: ['currentColor', 'inherit', 'initial', 'transparent', 'unset'] },
        ],
        'order/properties-alphabetical-order': true,
        'function-url-quotes': 'always',
        'selector-class-pattern': null,
        'no-eol-whitespace': null,
        'selector-nested-pattern': ['^&'],
        'no-descending-specificity': null,
        'at-rule-no-unknown': [true, { ignoreAtRules: ['mixin', 'define-mixin'] }],
        'plugin/kebab-case-or-wp-vars': true,
        'custom-property-pattern': null,
    },
};
```

And the following code still works, when it shouldn't:

```css
.testing {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--testing--primary-color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the built-in [custom-property-pattern](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/custom-property-pattern/) rule to do this, rather than write a custom plugin:

```
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    "custom-property-pattern": [
      "^(wp--)?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(-[a-z0-9]+)*$", {
        message: (name) => `Expected custom property name "${name}" to be kebab-case with an optional "wp--" prefix`,
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

This will allow:

```
a {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: var(--wp--primary-color);
}
```

And disallow:

```
a {
  background-color: var(--primaryColor);
  color: var(--testing--primary-color);
}
```